# update entity object along with its updated navigation properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-database-first

I am using database first approach of EF in an asp.net mvc application, and I have generated entity classes something like this..

```
public class BenchmarkRange
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int GoodForm { get; set; }
    public int GoodTo { get; set; }
    //...
    public ICollection<PerformanceScores> PerformanceScores { get; set; }
}

public class PerformanceScores
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int BenchmarkRangeID { get; set; }
    public int RangeFrom { get; set; }
    public int RangeTo { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }

    public BenchmarkRange BenchmarkRange { get; set; }
}
```

now, I send the `BenchmarkRange` object to view..

some editing happens at clientside and I get the model back by default model binding and it will have `PerformanceScores` with some edited, some newly added, some deleted from the collection.

How do I update `BenchmarkRange` with updated `PerformanceScores`?

Actually I don't have exact idea how do I do this. I tried by getting the same object from database and comparing it with new one, but its throwing error something like `..multiple objects with same key cannot be tracked by the ObjectstateManager..`

Could please someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new class (a viewModel) and put both entities in that class. You can see more detail with a full example here...

[Getting error on POST with Entity Framework - Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432776/getting-error-on-post-with-entity-framework-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-na)

Comment: This might be better - either one should give you the start you need... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19427402/updating-a-collection-of-classes-or-viewmodel/19428986#19428986