# Getting error on POST with Entity Framework - Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-database-first

EDIT - as requested, this is the view...

--start edit

```
@model salesWebTest.viewModel.vwbooking

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.bookings.bookingid)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.bookings.name)

@foreach (var item in Model.traces)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => item.contact_Name)
}
}
```

--end edit

--start original question
I have a viewModel that contains two classes...

```
public class vwbooking
{
    public booking bookings { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<trace> traces { get; set; }
}
```

Booking and trace are entities in an edmx.

I want to update the data in these two class with one call to save.

This is what I've tried...

```
public ActionResult Edit(vwbooking vwbooking)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.bookings.Attach(vwbooking.bookings);
        db.Entry(vwbooking.bookings).State = EntityState.Modified;
        vwbooking.traces.ToList().ForEach( //THE ERROR OCCURS HERE
                  t =>
                  {
                      db.traces.Attach(t);
                      db.Entry(t).State = EntityState.Modified;
                  });
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

If I remove the traces portion, the booking portion will update correctly.

This is the GET method...

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
{
    booking booking = db.bookings.Find(id);
    var viewModel = new vwbooking();
    viewModel.bookings = booking;
    viewModel.traces = (from l in db.traces where l.bookingid == booking.bookingid select l);
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

This is my db context class

```
public class salesContext : DbContext
{
    public salesContext() : base()
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }

    public salesContext(string Connection) : base(Connection)
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }

    public DbSet<booking> bookings { get; set; }
    public DbSet<trace> traces { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<booking>().HasKey(e => e.bookingid);
        modelBuilder.Entity<trace>().HasKey(e => e.traceid);
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that `vwbooking.traces` is null.

Comment: Right - its is - but why? There are 3 items that display on the page, and I know there are 3 entries in the db. Its as though they aren't passed, even though vwbooking.bookings is.

Comment: How have you displayed it in the view? When you post back is it in the post paramaters? If not try to add it to the view with Html.DisplayFor or Html.HiddenFor. This way it must be posted back.

Comment: This is how its used in the view...


`@foreach (var item in Model.traces)
{
@Html.EditorFor(m => item.contact_Name)
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be the way the editor is setup. I believe that this is causing the model to not properly bind on submit

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => item.contact_Name)
```

If you were to inspect the `name` attribute of the `<input>` element generated by this helper, you will more than likely see that it reads

```
<input name="item.contact_Name" />
```

for every one of these. It may even just say `name="contact_Name"`.

This is a severe drawback of the framework and the workarounds for it are usually to make a whole custom helper or to use a front end solution to fix the names.

The name must match *exactly* to the model. What it should be for your values is

```
<input name="traces[0].contact_Name" />
<input name="traces[1].contact_Name" />
etc..
```

and so I would suggest figuring out a way that works with your current project to make sure that those names get properly set.

Comment: Major drawback is an understatement. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your not checking if vwbooking.traces == null before calling it. While you might expect that .ToList() can protect you from this, Entity Framework can be quirky (anecdotal). Safeguard your call with

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{

    db.bookings.Attach(vwbooking.bookings);
    db.Entry(vwbooking.bookings).State = EntityState.Modified;
    if(vwbooking.traces != null)
    {
            vwbooking.traces.ToList().ForEach( //THE ERROR OCCURS HERE
            t =>
            {
            db.traces.Attach(t);
            db.Entry(t).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
        );
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

and you should be fine.

Comment: The issue is that traces should not be null. This does prevent the page from returning the error, but the data doesn't get updated.