# Model binding to a list EditorFor compilation error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, ef-database-first

What I'm trying to do here appears to be pretty common, but I can't run this code. I get a compilation error.

I'm trying to bind to an ienumerable or icollection in a viewmodel. Is my syntax wrong? Is there a  new way of doing thing I missed.

```
@for(var i=0; i < Model.traces.Count(); ++i)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.traces[i].status)
}
```

The details of my architecture are at a previous post of mine that led to this...

[Getting error on POST with Entity Framework - Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432776/getting-error-on-post-with-entity-framework-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-na)

Comment: Did you checked the post parameters in the request?

Comment: thanks again for all your help in previous posts jannagy. This was a tough one I'm happy to be done with!

Comment: I am glad to hear it's done :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is my syntax wrong?

Yes, IEnumerable or ICollection do not have indexer: `x.traces[i]`.

It would be better if you used a collection whose elements can be accessed by index such as `IList<T>` or `T[]`, depending on the concrete type of your view model.

Then you will be able to do this:

```
@model IList<MyViewModel>
...
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.traces.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.traces[i].status)
}
```

Comment: Yes - list fixed this issue - my final razor syntax is this...

@for(var i=0; i < Model.traces.Count(); ++i)

                                        {


                                            @Html.TextBox("traces["+i+"].status", Model.traces[i].status)


                                            @Html.TextBox("traces["+i+"].contact_Name", 

Model.traces[i].contact_Name)


                                        }

Answer (score 0):

The framework is quite smart in this case, if you have made your own EditorTemplate for the model `Trace`, you can actually just write

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.traces)
```

and MVC will render an editor for each item in the list and give you the right fieldnames for each index.

Comment: I've looked into this, but as I understand it, I have to create the template in a way that tells the framework how to write the html, which is the part I'm failing at. Do you have a link you could point me to?

Comment: Can you post the `Trace` class? I can show you how to make a template for it.